# Does invisibility allow you to see through the object you cast it on?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, invisibility

The *invisibility* spell specifically states:

> The creature or object touched becomes invisible, vanishing from sight, even from darkvision.

When *invisibility* is cast on an object in a square that blocks line of sight, is blocked line of sight negated?

Comment: I refer you to the response I made to your deleted comment, a real object blocks line of sight. The invisibility spell confers invisibility on a real object however it does not negate a blocked line of sight through a real object. Because if it did it would be detailed as a property in the spell description. the X-Ray vision example is not a non sequitur because unlike invisibility it DOES negate blocked line of sight through a real object.

Comment: @MichaelDorf Regarding your interpretation of the rules. Were I to cast invisibility on a closed door, I can no longer see the door as it has vanished from sight. What then do I see if I look in the direction of the door if not the room beyond the door? I can logically understand your argument for line of sight but have trouble resolving that into an actual outcome.

Comment: @linksassin The answer to that is beyond the scope of the question. If you mean by outcome 'what does my character perceive being that I know there is an invisible door there?' the answer is 'A character faced with proof that an illusion isn’t real needs no saving throw.' you perceive the door. https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#illusion

Comment: What would a character who does **not** know that the door is there see when looking through the doorway, then? They would not know there's an illusion, and therefore would not automatically overcome the supposed illusion effect. And the invisibility spell itself offers no save; they have **no** way of seeing the door until they bump into it. What, then, *do* they see?

Answer (score 13):

The object becomes invisible, so things behind it are visible through it.  Making a door invisible would indeed allow vision into the room beyond, at least the parts that can be seen from the door frame.  An invisible object is see-through, doesn't block light passing through it.

"Seeing" an invisible creature would be trivial if this wasn't the case.  Simply look for the human-shaped hole you can't see through.

Note that while invisible creatures and objects don't block line of sight, they still block line of effect - targeting a *fireball* behind an invisible door will cause the *fireball* to impact the door, detonating earlier than expected.

Comment: An invisible thing can be seen through.  That's part of being invisible.  That's what the word means.  It isn't my opinion, it's the definition of the word.  If they couldn't be seen through, you would be able to see them.

Answer (score 7):

Invisibility is of the glamer subschool of illusion. Those spells, while they do not create a physical effect, adjust the qualities of an object with regard to the senses. Invisibility, for example, physically makes an object visually disappear. This is as opposed to a phantasm, which is mind affecting, or a figment which provides false sensory input to creatures and requires knowledge of what you want the sensory input to be.

Since the object is altered by a glamer to no longer be visible, the illusion spell does not require any divination to know what is behind the door. Instead, the object is simply no longer visible, and so the objects behind it become visible when they are no longer blocked by the disappeared object.

Note that a glamer does not necessarily project an image of the casters choosing. Instead, it specifically affects the sensory qualities of the subject. That is why the contents of the room behind an invisible door are visible. The door is simply no longer interacting with light but instead allowing light to pass through it unimpeded.

I wanted to add, regarding this info for glamers and figments:

> Because figments and glamers (see below) are unreal, they cannot produce real effects the way that other types of illusions can. They cannot cause damage to objects or creatures, support weight, provide nutrition, or provide protection from the elements. Consequently, these spells are useful for confounding or delaying foes, but useless for attacking them directly.

The context of that statement is in comparison to shadow and phantasm spells which create physical and/or dangerous constructs capable of harming creatures. A glamer illusion *does* alter the physical interaction of its subject with regard to the senses, but it cannot produce any effect that can otherwise interact with the world. For example, a glamer could make a person smell bad, but it could not make them emit a stinking cloud. Anything smelling the subject could find the smell revolting, but it cannot make them nauseated because it cannot produce toxic gas as a shadow spell could, nor could it strike victims with fear or kill them as a phantasm could.

Comment: Appreciate the input but none of that about 'so the objects behind it become visible when they are no longer blocked by the disappeared object' can be supported under the rules statement concerning glammer. The door is real it blocks line of sight. Page 139 PHB Two creatures can see each other if they can trace at least one clear straight line...The line is clear if it doesn't cross or even touch squares that block line of sight.'

Comment: @MichaelDorf So does a window block line of sight?

Comment: @ObliviousSage No a window does not block line of sight.

Comment: @MichaelDorf If you have your own answer to the question, your should provide it as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118210/discussion-between-michaeldorf-and-hey-i-can-chan).

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

There are only 4 ways in which invisibility can work, at least that I can think of right now (feel free to comment/edit if you can think of more):

1. The spell turns you physically transparent, altering the matter that composes you so that light goes through you instead of colliding with you and bouncing off, like glass. In this case you would see what is behind a closed door.
2. The spell affects the path the light follows when colliding with you, instead of bouncing off the light goes around you and then it follows it's previous path behind you, effectively dodging you. In this case you would see what is behind a closed door.
3. The spell just changes the color of your body and equipment so that it matches exactly whatever is behind you, kind of like a chameleon works but much better. In this case the invisible door would indeed block line of sight, but you would still be seeing the door, and it would look exactly like what's behind it, so there wouldn't be any difference effectively.
4. The spell alters the mind of those who see the invisible creature and makes them ignore it, kind of like the Hide from X spells work. This case could be problematic, and maybe this is how you're interpreting invisibility, with the door example in this case, since you wouldn't be able to see the door, nor what's behind it, maybe you would just see darkness, it would be a GM's call.

The only option that works with your interpretation would be option 4, but since Invisibility is an Illusion spell, and the spells that hide a creature in this way are Abjuration spells, like Hide from Undead, or Hide from Dragons, we can conclude that this isn't how the Invisibility spell works.

I personally think the Invisibility spell works like option 3, since options 1 and 2 don't fall into the Illusion school, but there are some problems with this interpretation too, like what would happen with gaze attacks and other effects activated on sight when viewed through an invisible object/creature.

Comment: Your point 4 is how psionic invisibility works in 2e - it's a telepathic power that requires you to make contact with the individuals you want to become invisible to, and maintain the power separately for each "pair" (so, to make 3 people invisible to 2 guards, 6 copies of the power).  But that version _only_ works for creatures, you can't use it on a door to start with.